# Split With negative numbers as delimiter

Tags: ruby

How to split with -ve numbers as delimiter in RUBY for example
if x = 989-7516-354
if we use split now then it should print 
9,8,9,5,1,6,5,4

Comment: What does "-ve" mean? What is `989-7516-354`, a string? How is your result / output related to the delimiters? `-7` and `-3` just seem to be missing. If they were delimiters, the result should be `989`, `516` and `54`.

Answer (score 2):

You question is not very clear. Splitting with negative number(assumption: single digit) as delimiter will give

`["989", "516", "54"]`.

To get the desired output, try this.

```
x = "989-7516-354"
x.gsub(/-\d/, '').chars
# => ["9", "8", "9", "5", "1", "6", "5", "4"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x.split(/-\d/).map{|n| n.split(//)}.flatten
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = '989-7516-354'
x.split(/(-\d)?/).map(&:to_i).reject(&:negative?)
# => [9, 8, 9, 5, 1, 6, 5, 4]
```

Comment: This is not the expected output.

Comment: @Santhosh ty for pointing this, I edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [a negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), you just need to [scan](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-scan) the string for digits not preceded by `-`:

```
"989-7516-354".scan(/(?<!-)\d/)
# => ["9", "8", "9", "5", "1", "6", "5", "4"]
```